# A SyntaxError:invalid character in identifier. But I don't why it goes wrong

Tags: python, syntax-error

I created a function to compare the characters in my_word and other_word. my_word is a string with '_' characters, other_word is a string with regular English word.

The function returns: boolean, True if all the actual letters of my_word match the
corresponding letters of other_word, or the letter is the special symbol
'_' , and my_word and other_word are of the same length;False otherwise.

Hint:, the letter (_ ) cannot be one
of the letters in the other_word that has already been revealed. So if run  match_with_gaps("a_ ple", "apple") ,it returns False.

Here is the code:

```
`def match_with_gaps(my_word, other_word):
    my_word=my_word.replace(' ','')
    if len(my_word)==len(other_word):
        for char1 in my_word:
            if char1 not in other_word and char1 != '_':
                return False
        my_list=list(my_word)
        other_list=list(other_word)
        for w in my_list:
            if other_list.count(w)>1：
              return False
        return True
    else: return False`
```

Run the code. It returns SyntaxError:invalid character in identifier

with the line: if other_list.count(w)>1. But I think it is acceptable to use the list.count() function.
What's wrong with it?

Comment: Possibly you have some invisible character embedded there in your actual code.  Delete the line and re-type it.

Comment: Please provide full tracebacks - `[].count(5)>1` is perfectly valid syntax.  I would, however, strongly suggest some spacing around the comparison operator, and IIRC that's PEP8 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and cleaned it up.  The colon after 1 was not recognized as a colon.  You also had a ' character at the start and end of your code.  This works fine now:

```
def match_with_gaps(my_word, other_word):
    my_word=my_word.replace(' ','')
    if len(my_word)==len(other_word):
        for char1 in my_word:
            if char1 not in other_word and char1 != '_':
                return False
        my_list=list(my_word)
        other_list=list(other_word)
        for w in my_list:
            if other_list.count(w)>1:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: The extra quote characters were probably a misguided attempt to format the text as code.

Comment: Good catch on the colon.  It's actually U+FF1A which is [full width colon](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff1a/index.htm).

Comment: Thanks! It solved this problem. I put a colon that is not recognized as a colon.

Comment: Actually, the right code to achieve the requirement should change the line: if other_list.count(w)>1: to if other_list.count(w)>my_list.count(w):